# low disk space, backup error

Tags: backup

how can I modify or create again the whole process of creating a backup in Windows Backup?

I'm doing until now backup to an external drive, and when it ran out of space on the backup fails.

It is possible that the automatic Windows Backup delete the oldest backup?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Delete files older than x-days - Cleanup Script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Delete-files-older-than-x-13b29c09) from technet gallery.
Set number of days for which you want backups to be stored.